# read JSON object gives error "int expected"

Tags: c#, json

Using this snippet I am able to recieve a string which I convert to JSON object.

```
var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWORD") };
var response = client.DownloadString(@"someURL");

var jo = JObject.Parse(@response);

Console.WriteLine(jo["result"]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

My JSON:

[image]

I would like to work with the value in "text" - I tried `Console.WriteLine(jo["result"]["text"]);` but it gives me the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: "Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "text". Int32 array index expected."

Comment: If possible, please avoid images of code. Some people explained, why they don't like images: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: That's an array.

The array indexer that JSON.NET is asking for is `[0]` in `jo["result"][0]["text"]` to access the first array element. See duplicate.

Comment: Error says everything. Array expects index value, not a string. Use 0,1,2,3...instead "text

Comment: try 

    Console.WriteLine(jo["result"][0]["text"]);

because of json string format.

in your json, result convered with []